# How to initialize global list in page and use it in another page in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, initialization

I have this list `List<Cart> carts` and I want to initialize it in login page `carts = List()` and I want to add it on another page `carts.add(...)`

When I use this it throws an exception:

```
The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(Instance of 'Cart')
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your list on the page which you want to add items to it. The better way, you can use the app state provider to define and use a list on different pages. For more information, please check this [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Comment: I can't initialize list on page which I want to use it لاecause it will be created every time I open the page(actually the page is popup), and I want to add it to the list, not from the beginning 
and thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Because before adding any item into the list, you need to initialise it.

```
List<Cart> carts = new List();

//~~~~~~~ OR ~~~~~~~~~

List<Cart> carts = [];
```

Comment: yes I Know but I want to to add to it not from beginning

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I defined the global List and passed it as a parameter to the other page